# Z-index on multiple DIV containers and transparency not working

Tags: css

I have a page that contains multiple div containers. The first one  is a page container and the next one is a Modal  container.  Within the Modal container, I have first window container.  Outside of the Modal container, I have another DIV container for buttons.
What I want is to have both Modal container and button container at a different level(both at the same level) and  the rest in the lower layer, with a transparency  between them.

I have tried to capture the situation in(filter idea i got from  seaching stackoverflow questions):
    http://jsfiddle.net/Q2CNz/

```
#Modalcontainer {

position:absolute;
z-index :9999;    
background: transparent;
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00FFFFFF,endColorstr=#00FFFFFF)";
/* IE8 */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00FFFFFF, endColorstr=#00FFFFFF);
    /* IE6 & 7 */
    zoom: 1;
}
```

I am running into couple of problems in IE:

a) Stuff in first window and  and button container are not on the same level. This may be something to do with postion? I tried a few combos and nothing worked
b) There is no transparency between the stuff at the higher level and the one at lower level.
This stuff is  used  in predominently IE6 onwards.
Please let me know , how I can achieve this. Please don't ask me to use jQuery, our mandate dpes NOT allow that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by a "transparency" between them.. what you've got in your code is a gradient (though it's starting from the same color as it's ending on), not an opacity (transparency) setting.

Also as far as them being both at the same level - yet on different levels? you wrote:

> What I want is to have both Modal container and button container at a different level(both at the same level)

do you mean lined up alongside each other instead of overlapping?

Since I'm not quite sure what you mean, I changed your example around and added an opacity on the modal container as well as a black to white gradient, and a background color on the page container so you can see the opacity.

http://jsfiddle.net/YCLnj/

```
#Pagecontent {
    background-color:#663333;
}
#Modalcontainer {
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    padding:30px;
    border:2px solid #000;
    z-index:9999;
    filter: alpha(opacity=70);
    opacity:0.7;
    -moz-opacity:0.7;
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#000000), to(#FFFFFF));
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(center top, #000000, #FFFFFF);
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(center top, #000000, #FFFFFF);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(center top, #000000, #FFFFFF);
    background:linear-gradient(center top, #000000, #FFFFFF) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;

    filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#000000, endColorstr=#FFFFFF)";

    /* For Internet Explorer 8 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#330000, endColorstr=#FFFFFF)";

   /* IE6 & 7 */
   zoom: 1; 
}

#buttonContainer {
    position:relative;
    z-index:9999;
    background:transparent;
    padding:10px;
    width:100px;
    border: 2px dotted #CC33FF;
}
```

If you meant for the divs to be overlapping each other, you would just change the position to absolute on each of them and adjust the z-index accordingly, with the lowest number being placed at the bottom and highest on top. You would probably want to put the button layer on the top in that case, as otherwise the user won't be able to access the buttons to click.

Comment: Reading  my question, I realize  it was not very well written. But, your answers were what I was looking for.a) I started of wanting model container and button container overlapping instead of alongside, but since the model container has dynamic content, I think I am better off alongside.  I think the mistake I made  is that I did not have a Z-index on #behind.Is that required? I would have imagined it would be the under the stack ,  if I did not assign anything. b) I meant to say "opacity" but instead called it transparency.  Does "opacity" work in   IE browsers older than IE8?